# Yahoo Mail forwarding?

Tags: email, forwarding, yahoo-mail

Is there any way to have my Yahoo Mail forwarded to another email address, without getting Yahoo Mail plus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by setting my preferred content to Yahoo Asia, it enables the settings in the mail options.

Dunno how long it will last though!

Comment: It seems that this solution does not work anymore.

Comment: It used to work for yahoo.com.au (not yahoo.com). Does it still work now?

Answer (score 3):

You cant.. you need [yahoo mail plus](http://help.yahoo.com/tutorials/cg/mail/cg_access5.html). Its their way of making money off email.